# Array content does not display

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a div with id wheel, and the content will display going through the loop games[i] where i is 0, but will not shows the content if I append games[0]. Why?

I have included the entire code below. When you click the button it will display 123, but it should display 123 twice, but the games[0] does not append.

```
  <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#run").click(function(){

        ReadLine();

    });


});

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------- FUNCTIONS -------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------

function ReadLine()
{

    var games = new Array(new Array());
    var numbers = [1,2,3];
    games.push(numbers);

    for(var i=0; i<games.length; i++)
    {
        $("#wheel").append(games[i]);
    }
        $("#wheel").append(games[0]);
}

</script>


</head>
<body>

<input id="run" type="button" value="Run" onclick="Run();" />
<p>
<div class="container" id="wheel" style="overflow: auto; width:870px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to know why games[i] displays, but not games[0] when i can be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are creating an `Array` with an empty `Array` in first (`0`) position:

```
[[]]
```

Then when you make the push, you get:

```
[[], [1, 2, 3]]
```

So, in `games[0]`, there is an empty `Array`.

See the logs in [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/m0q6r85v/).

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had to declare a multi-dimensional array like above. I did not know it actually put a blank one in. Thanks